# Four fair coins are to be flipped. What is the probability that all four will be heads or all four will be tails?

Tags: combinatorics

Four fair coins are to be flipped. What is the probability that all four will be heads or all four will be tails? Express your answer as a common fraction.
I think it will be 1/16 since 2^4 but the system says it is wrong can someone help me?

Comment: $\left( \frac1{2} \right)^4$ looks like the probability all four will  be heads

Comment: But it is wrong

Comment: Your question says *"What is the probability that all four will be heads or all four will be tails?"*

Answer (score 0):

P(TTTT) = $\frac{1}{2^{4}}$

P(HHHH) = $\frac{1}{2^{4}}$

P(TTTT or HHHH) = P(TTTT) + P(HHHH) = $\frac{1}{8}$